# Automatically raise accelerator while riding on my bike

Tags: acceleration

I have a honda 125 cc bike. Recently i have found some problem with the accelerator. Accelerator automatically getting raised . I am not sure whether it is problem with accelerator.I have changed my accelerator cable twice. But the problem still persists. I have consulted with two mechanics, but they said they didnt saw any problem with the bike. Can any one have any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean "raised" ? It sticks open? It closes automatically? It accelerates by itself ie continues to open until full throttle?

Comment: It accelerates by itself. Continues to open until full throttle

Comment: Is there a blockage in the carburettor causing the piston to rise? Check the air channels and make sure they are clear

Comment: Ok. But i feel some tightness in the accelerator. Is the carburetor issue cause any tightness in the accelerator??? I have replaced the accelerator cable twice, but the issue still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its carbeurated you could have bad carbeurators or floats. If so, CAREFULLY clean them and finely adjust them and the throttle body.  -not responsible for lost carb parts and maybe adjust the idle?